# XtraGrid: Show custom Row Indicator icon

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

How to show custom row indicator icon in DevExpress **XtraGrid** control?

[This example](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawRowIndicatortopic) demonstrate showing text in RowIndicator column. But I want to show custom images/icons from Resources based on some conditions.

And in [this example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2841), the error icon is shown.

Here is my code:

```
Private cObj_ImageList As ImageList
cObj_ImageList = New ImageList()
cObj_ImageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.lock_red)
cObj_ImageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.unlock_blue)

Private Sub GridView_CustomDrawRowIndicator(sender As Object, e As RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs)

    If e.Info.IsRowIndicator And e.RowHandle >= 0 Then
        Try
            For Each lObj_ChngdRow As ChangedRow In cObj_Lst_ChngdRows
                If lObj_ChngdRow.CRRowHandle = e.RowHandle And lObj_ChngdRow.IsEditable Then

                    'e.Graphics.DrawIcon(cObj_RowStateUnlock, 0, 0)
                    'e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(My.Resources.unlock_blue, 0, 0)

                    e.Info.ImageIndex = -1

                    e.Painter.DrawObject(e.Info)

                    Dim rec As Rectangle = e.Bounds

                    rec.Inflate(-1, -1)

                    Dim x1 As Integer = rec.X + (rec.Width - cObj_ImageList.ImageSize.Width) / 2


                    Dim y1 As Integer = rec.Y + (rec.Height - cObj_ImageList.ImageSize.Height) / 2

                    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(cObj_ImageList.Images(1), x1, y1)

                    e.Handled = True

                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]
This shows icon for one row only. I want to show for all rows. But when a button **Checkout** is clicked, I want to change this icon.

**EDIT 1:**

As nempoBu4 explained, I have modified my code to rather more simpler:

```
Private Sub GridView_CustomDrawRowIndicator(sender As Object, e As RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs)

    Try
        If e.Info.IsRowIndicator And e.RowHandle >= 0 Then

            e.Handled = True

            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(cObj_ImageList.Images(0), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)

            Dim lObj_ChngdRow = cObj_Lst_ChngdRows.Find(Function(item) item.CRRowHandle = e.RowHandle AndAlso item.IsEditable)

            If Not lObj_ChngdRow Is Nothing Then

                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(cObj_ImageList.Images(1), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)

            End If

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

See the attached Screenshot.

[image]

Red and Blue icons are on top of each others. I think I have to clear the ImageList and then add them again.

Comment: You want to change the icon for currently selected row?

Comment: What is the code of your `Checkout` button?

Comment: @nempoBu4 Yup! But only when **Checkout** button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CustomDrawRowIndicator` event is firing for each row individually, so you don't need to use the cycle through all objects in your `cObj_Lst_ChngdRows` collection. Also you need to invalidate row indicator after adding an object to your `cObj_Lst_ChngdRows` collection. For this you need to use [`GridView.InvalidateRowIndicator`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_InvalidateRowIndicatortopic) method.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub CheckoutButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim rowHandle = gvException.FocusedRowHandle

    Dim row = New ChangedRow()
    row.CRRowHandle = rowHandle
    row.IsEditable = True

    cObj_Lst_ChngdRows.Add(row)

    gvException.InvalidateRowIndicator(rowHandle)

End Sub

Private Sub GridView_CustomDrawRowIndicator(sender As Object, e As RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs)
    If e.Info.IsRowIndicator AndAlso e.RowHandle >= 0 Then
        Try
            Dim lObj_ChngdRow = cObj_Lst_ChngdRows.Find(Function(item) item.CRRowHandle = e.RowHandle AndAlso item.IsEditable)

            If Not lObj_ChngdRow Is Nothing Then
                e.Info.ImageIndex = -1
                e.Painter.DrawObject(e.Info)

                Dim rec As Rectangle = e.Bounds

                rec.Inflate(-1, -1)

                Dim x1 As Integer = rec.X + (rec.Width - cObj_ImageList.ImageSize.Width) / 2
                Dim y1 As Integer = rec.Y + (rec.Height - cObj_ImageList.ImageSize.Height) / 2

                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(cObj_ImageList.Images(1), x1, y1)
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1**

You are calling to `e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled` method twice. You need to call this method only one time.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub GridView_CustomDrawRowIndicator(sender As Object, e As RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs)

    Try
        If e.Info.IsRowIndicator And e.RowHandle >= 0 Then
            e.Handled = True

            Dim lObj_ChngdRow = cObj_Lst_ChngdRows.Find(Function(item) item.CRRowHandle = e.RowHandle AndAlso item.IsEditable)

            Dim imageIndex As Integer

            If lObj_ChngdRow Is Nothing Then
                imageIndex = 0
            Else
                imageIndex = 1
            End If

            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(cObj_ImageList.Images(imageIndex), e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the problem is, it shows two images on top of each other. Why its is so?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher I have checked my code and there are no problems. What have you tried? Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher You need to use only one `e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled` method.

Comment: O yes! Now that's true and working as per requirements. Thanks a lot buddy.